# How to troubleshooting single failure of scheduled app script

Tags: google-apps-script

I use google scripts to schedule moving, cleaning and archiving data. We recently had a script fail that aggregates staff contacts into a master list. It only appears to have failed once but failed before an important communication went out. It appears it could not call a required csv file but looking at the logs of another script it looks like the file did exist. Does anyone have any recommendations outside of chalking this up to a random google apps scripts service failure?

```
function import() {
 importCSVFromGoogleDrive('1vnTdA0yJEra1zCwLv5PKGxkTSrGxA4G-','A01_Contacts.csv','01')
 importCSVFromGoogleDrive('1vnTdA0yJEra1zCwLv5PKGxkTSrGxA4G-','A02_Contacts.csv','02')
 importCSVFromGoogleDrive('1vnTdA0yJEra1zCwLv5PKGxkTSrGxA4G-','A03_Contacts.csv','03')
 importCSVFromGoogleDrive('1vnTdA0yJEra1zCwLv5PKGxkTSrGxA4G-','A04_Contacts.csv','04')
 importCSVFromGoogleDrive('1vnTdA0yJEra1zCwLv5PKGxkTSrGxA4G-','A05_Contacts.csv','05')
 importCSVFromGoogleDrive('1vnTdA0yJEra1zCwLv5PKGxkTSrGxA4G-','A06_Contacts.csv','06')
 importCSVFromGoogleDrive('1vnTdA0yJEra1zCwLv5PKGxkTSrGxA4G-','A07_Contacts.csv','07')
 importCSVFromGoogleDrive('1vnTdA0yJEra1zCwLv5PKGxkTSrGxA4G-','A08_Contacts.csv','08')
 importCSVFromGoogleDrive('1vnTdA0yJEra1zCwLv5PKGxkTSrGxA4G-','A09_Contacts.csv','09')
 importCSVFromGoogleDrive('1vnTdA0yJEra1zCwLv5PKGxkTSrGxA4G-','A10_Contacts.csv','10')
 importCSVFromGoogleDrive('1vnTdA0yJEra1zCwLv5PKGxkTSrGxA4G-','A11_Contacts.csv','11')
 importCSVFromGoogleDrive('1vnTdA0yJEra1zCwLv5PKGxkTSrGxA4G-','A12_Contacts.csv','12')


}


function importCSVFromGoogleDrive(FolderID,FileName,SheetName) {
  var folder =DriveApp.getFolderById(FolderID)
  var file = folder.getFilesByName(FileName).next();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SheetName);  
  sheet.clear();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
 // You can use commands like the following to dictate the data formatting of some columns after     import
  // sheet.getRange("R:R").setNumberFormat('@STRING@');

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PXE9.png)

Comment: Sometimes, there's a delay when you call out to a file using the drive api, and the script will continue as if the file doesn't exist.  You might want to investigate the Google Cloud stuff, or some other file storage option.

Comment: Could you provide the error message with the line where it happened?

Comment: Thanks for the help!The error is TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined. 
at imprortCSVFromGoogleDrive(Import:26)
at import(Import:8)

Comment: What about purring the csv call in a try loop that loops until it is successful? It looks like it fails very infrequently

Comment: That makes sense, although you might want to limit it to 10 or 20 tries.  Until successful implies an endless loop if it really can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

It may not solve the problem but it should leave you with a bit more information when it happens.

```
function import() {
  var fA=[{filename:'A01_Contacts.csv',sheetname:'01'},{filename:'A02_Contacts.csv',sheetname:'02'},{filename:'A03_Contacts.csv',sheetname:'03'},{filename:'A04_Contacts.csv',sheetname:'04'},{filename:'A05_Contacts.csv',sheetname:'05'},{filename:'A06_Contacts.csv',sheetname:'06'},{filename:'A07_Contacts.csv',sheetname:'07'},{filename:'A08_Contacts.csv',sheetname:'08'},{filename:'A09_Contacts.csv',sheetname:'09'},{filename:'A10_Contacts.csv',sheetname:'10'},{filename:'A11_Contacts.csv',sheetname:'11'},{filename:'A12_Contacts.csv',sheetname:'12'}];
  var id='1vnTdA0yJEra1zCwLv5PKGxkTSrGxA4G-';
  Logger.log(importCSV({files:fA,folderid:id}));
}

function importCSV(obj) {
  var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById(obj.folderid);
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  obj['status']=[];
  obj.files.forEach(function(O,i){
    try {
      var csvData=Utilities.parseCsv(folder.getFilesByName(O.filename).next().getBlob().getDataAsString());
      if(csvData) {
        var sh=ss.getSheetByName(O.sheetName);
        sh.clear();
        sh.getRange(1,1,csvData.length,csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
        obj.status=Utilities.formatString('Success: FileName: %s SheetName: %s',O.filename,O.sheetname);
      }
    }
    catch(e) {
      obj.status=Utilities.formatString('Error: %s, Failure: FileName: %s SheetName: %s',e,O.filename,O.sheetname);
    }
  });
  return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error "TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined" you're getting is caused by trying to access the length of the `csvData` array's first value when the `csvData` is an empty array (because the .csv file is empty), you can prevent this by using and `if` for when the `csvData` array is empty, like this:

```
function importCSVFromGoogleDrive(FolderID,FileName,SheetName) {
  var folder =DriveApp.getFolderById(FolderID)
  var file = folder.getFilesByName(FileName).next();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SheetName);  
  sheet.clear();
  if( csvData.length == 0) { return }
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
}
```